# NullPointerException em java. Salvar imagem na pasta bin para que o software execute sem erros?

Tags: java, imagem, nullpointerexception

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em **java** e colocando imagens em `jLabels`, porém, toda vez que vou executar o programa, ele aparece uma mensagem "`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`" e não executa, carrega até 50%.

*Quando eu vou em propriedades do jLabel, clico em icon e redefinir como padrão, o jLabel fica sem imagem e o programa roda normalmente.*

Durante minha pesquisa eu encontrei pessoas falando que o meu código estava retornando null na imagem... Segue o código:

```
jLabelImgLogoInicial.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/view/gui/img/logoempregoinicial.png"))); // NOI18N
```

O meu problema é que o caminho certo para a imagem seria "`/img/logoempregoinicial.png`", porém, quando insiro a imagem, o netbeans automaticamente cria o endereço do código anterior e resulta no retorno null, pois ele não vai encontrar a imagem.

Segue a imagem da arquitetura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a pilha de erros:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at view.gui.LogoInicial.initComponents(LogoInicial.java:47)
    at view.gui.LogoInicial.<init>(LogoInicial.java:20)
    at view.gui.MainEmpreGO.<init>(MainEmpreGO.java:19)
    at view.gui.MainEmpreGO$6.run(MainEmpreGO.java:278)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

*Li que para solucionar esse problema, é necessário salvar as imagens
em uma pasta "bin" do netbeans, porém não encontrei essa pasta.*

> Como encontro a pasta bin do netbeans para salvar a imagem e esse
>   problema não ocorrer mais e por quê é necessário salvar
>   especificamente nessa pasta para que o programa não coloque um caminho
>   diferente do que o que eu necessito?

Fonte pesquisada:
[Why does my icon handling code throw a NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019914/why-does-my-icon-handling-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Cadê a pilha de erros?

Comment: Me esqueci de postar o print, vou editar a pergunta com o print @renan

Comment: editei a pergunta com a pilha de erros @diegofm

Comment: Já tentou passar o caminho por código, e não pelo editor do netbeans? E confirma ai onde é a linha 47 da classe LogoInicial.

Comment: Vou fazer testes aqui por código. A linha 47 é essa mesma "jLabelImgLogoInicial.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/view/gui/img/logoempregoinicial.png"))); // NOI18N"

Comment: Altere o endereço para `/main/java/view/gui/img/logoempregoinicial.png`

Comment: Está usando o `build.xml` gerado pelo NetBeans para construir o .jar, certo? Você fez alguma modificação ou está "do jeito que vem"? Só pra saber mesmo, acho que dá pra formular uma resposta.

Comment: Estou fazendo testes @diegofm obrigada pelas dicas.

Comment: @renan estou usando a opção padrão do netbeans, mas fique a vontade para postar sua resposta, talvez eu tente da sua maneira e solucione o meu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos lá!

O NetBeans tem duas maneiras de criar projetos Java:

1. Uma é clicando em Arquivo, Novo Projeto, **Categoria: Java** -> Aplicação Java. Esta maneira vou chamar de **Projeto ANT**.
2. A segunda é clicando em Arquivo, Novo Projeto, **Categoria: Maven** -> Aplicação Java. Esta maneira vou chamar de **Projeto Maven**.

**Projetos ANT** usam uma ferramenta chamada **ant** para gerenciar o processo de construção da aplicação. Este tipo de projeto é fácil de reconhecer pelo arquivo **build.xml** encontrado na raiz do projeto.

**Projetos Maven** usam uma ferramenta chamada **Maven**, também para gerenciar o processo de construção da aplicação(e muitíssimo mais). Dá para reconhecer projetos de Java Maven por diversas maneiras:

- Eles possuem um arquivo **pom.xml** na raiz do projeto.
- Eles possuem uma estrutura de pastas específica:

  - Os arquivos *.java* ficam dentro de ***src/main/java***
  - Arquivos de recursos, sejam textos, ícones, configuração, ficam em ***src/main/resources***
  - Classes de teste Java(que também são *.java*) ficam em de ***src/test/java***
  - E arquivos de recursos usados somente nos testes, ficam em ***src/test/resources***
- Quando o Maven compila as classes, ele junta ambos o ***src/main/java*** e o ***src/main/resources***, e joga o resultado já compilado para ***target/classes***.

Agora o mais importante:

- Se houver qualquer arquivo diferente de *.java* dentro de ***src/main/java***, ele irá ignorá-los totalmente. Até mesmo as pastas sem arquivos Java são ignoradas! Se quiser que estes arquivos estejam contidos na tua aplicação, eles deveriam estar dentro de ***src/main/resources*** !!

---

Olhando para tua estrutura de pastas, vi que ele é um projeto Maven, e portanto, a solução é criar uma pasta ***src/main/resources/view/gui/img*** e mover o arquivo **logoempregoinicial.png** para dentro dela.

Comment: Nenhum dos projetos do netbeans que tenho aqui segue essa estrutura que você falou ai, todos tem apenas a pasta src seguida dos packages que eu mesmo criei no projeto, dentro da IDE, inclusive com arquivos diferentes de .java, que são reconhecidos e compilados juntos com o projeto normalmente.

Comment: diegofm, então você está usando um projeto ANT, e não um Maven, que é o caso da Marcielli. Por padrão o NetBeans cria os projetos usando ANT mesmo.

Comment: Agora fez mais sentido pra mim, olhando novamente a estrutura. Como ela não citou nada, deu a entender que ela que tinha criado.

Answer (score -2):

Cara estava com o mesmo problema com um projeto que exportei o pacote zip ou mesmo trazendo ele pelo compartilhamento do github, o que resolveu, eu comparando com um projeto de teste que fiz, vi a diferença entre um e outro percebi que a pasta que criei no diretório de arquivos do projeto não possuía a pasta com nome images no diretório src do projeto, o que fiz foi copiar a pasta images e colar em src, fechei o netbeans e pronto, funcionando sem erro.